# Flutter Mp3 audio file not detetcted

Tags: android, flutter, mp3, assets, pubspec

My android studio is not able to understand the file extension(.mp3). it gives (The asset does not exist or has empty data.) error even though files are present and path is correct . i rechecked the
pubpsec.yaml folder. it shows no error and i got Question mark (?) in front of my audio files and not able to click those files . they are not responding or opening. Here are pictures of them:
[image: audio assets]

and error shows like:
[image: error] .

How can I resolve this issue ??

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it seems like the path has double `assets/` path (`assets/assets/audio/download1.mp3`). Try to remove the unnecessary `assets/` path from wherever you're accessing that audio file.

Comment: The first asset is a section within the 'pubspec.yaml' file, while the second one is a directory I created to store audio files

Comment: How do you access it from the Dart code?

Comment: using audioplayer package audioplayer.play(AssetSource("path")) and using  provider for notifulisteners()

Comment: Eariler I was able to open my audiofiles after clicking them on Android Studio, but now even i am not to able to open files ,they are not responding

Comment: Are you sure it's related to the IDE you're using (in this case, Android Studio)? What happens if you open with VSCode?

Comment: No, I actually tried it on VS but it gives error like path not exist or data not found , even though in VS when i click on audio it plays audio , after lot of searching looks like there is an error in pubspec.yaml file but not able to figure out *path is correct